# How can I compare two 2D-array files with bash?

Tags: bash, multidimensional-array

I have two 2D-array files to read with `bash`.

What I want to do is extract the elements inside both files.

These two files contain different rows x columns such as:

**file1.txt (nx7)**

```
NO DESC ID TYPE W S GRADE
1 AAA 20 AD 100 100 E2 
2 BBB C0 U 200 200 D 
3 CCC 9G R 135 135 U1 
4 DDD 9H Z 246 246 T1 
5 EEE 9J R 789 789 U1 
.
.
.
```

**file2.txt (mx3)**

```
DESC W S 
AAA 100 100 
CCC 135 135
EEE 789 789
.
.
.
```

Here is what I want to do:

1. Extract the element in DESC column of **file2.txt** then find the corresponding element in **file1.txt**.
2. Extract the W,S elements in such row of **file2.txt** then find the corresponding W,S elements in such row of **file1.txt**.
3. If `[W1==W2 && S1==S2];` then `echo "${DESC[colindex]} ok";` else `echo "${DESC[colindex]} NG"`

How can I read this kind of file as a 2D array with bash or is there any convenient way to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the `join` command.

Comment: wait for @Kent 's answer, he sure will post an max. 30 character long awk script ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash does not support 2D arrays. You can simulate them by generating 1D array variables like `array1`, `array2`, and so on.

Assuming DESC is a key (i.e. has no duplicate values) and does not contain any spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read data from file1
idx=0
while read -a data$idx; do
    let idx++
done <file1.txt

# process data from file2
while read desc w2 s2; do
    for ((i=0; i<idx; i++)); do
        v="data$i[1]"
        [ "$desc" = "${!v}" ] && {
            w1="data$i[4]"
            s1="data$i[5]"
            if [ "$w2" = "${!w1}" -a "$s2" = "${!s1}" ]; then
                echo "$desc ok"
            else
                echo "$desc NG"
            fi
            break
        }
    done
done <file2.txt
```

For brevity, optimizations such as taking advantage of sort order are left out.

If the files actually contain the header `NO DESC ID TYPE ...` then use `tail -n +2` to discard it before processing.

A more elegant solution is also possible, which avoids reading the entire file in memory. This should only be relevant for really large files though.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to simulate 2D-arrays with bash, It's very useful to me!

Answer (score 0):

If the rows order is not needed be preserved (can be sorted), maybe this is enough:

```
join -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.5,2.6 <(tail -n +2 file2.txt|sort) <(tail -n +2 file1.txt|sort) |\
    sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \2 \3/\1 OK/' |\
    sed '/ OK$/!s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1 NG/'
```

For file1.txt

```
NO DESC ID TYPE W S GRADE
1 AAA 20 AD 100 100 E2 
2 BBB C0 U 200 200 D 
3 CCC 9G R 135 135 U1 
4 DDD 9H Z 246 246 T1 
5 EEE 9J R 789 789 U1
```

and file2.txt

```
DESC W S 
AAA 000 100 
CCC 135 135
EEE 789 000
FCK xxx 135
```

produces:

```
AAA NG
CCC OK
EEE NG
```

Explanation:

- skip the header line in both files - `tail +2`
- `sort` both files
- `join` the needed columns from both files into one table like, in the result will appears only the lines what has common DESC field

like next:

```
AAA 000 100 100 100
CCC 135 135 135 135
EEE 789 000 789 789
```

- in the lines, which have the same values in 2-4 and 3-5 columns, substitute every but 1st column with `OK`
- in the remainder lines substitute the columns with `NG`

Comment: At least in GNU tail, specifying `+2` requires using `-n` before it, as in `tail -n +2`. Otherwise, the "+2" is interpreted as a file name.

Comment: thanks for your explaination, it's also helpful to me